# How to export products from Magento to Woocommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, woocommerce, product

I need to move my 100s of products from `Magento ver. 1.7.0.2` to `WooCommerce 2.1.11`.

Is there any way to do this?

I have searched a lot but found nothing on this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Magento but a quick web search turns up several export to XML extensions. So if you can export successfully, I've found WP All Import (WP plug-in) with its WooCommerce add-on is able to import just about anything to WooCommerce - after a little setting up. It's not a *free* solution but it might save you a lot of time and money in the long run. (I'm not affiliated).

Comment: From magento addmin panel, you can export all the products. (System->Import/Export->Data Flow Profiles->Export All Products). It will create one csv file containing all your product details. Does woocommerce accepts bulk product import using csv? If so, you can use imported csv file from magento.

Comment: I have already exported CSV file, but I am finding problem in importing it to wp woocommerce

Comment: An automated tool or plugin may not cover all issues. This [Magento to WooCommerce](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-woocommerce/) migration service is exact what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Cart2Cart solutions is the best, though it might cost you a little.

Migrations of following is possible from magento to WooCommerce

1. Products, product images, product extra fields, product attributes, product variants
2. Categories, category images
3. Customers, customer shipping address, customer billing address
4. Orders, order statuses

Answer (score 1):

Not a fan of this plugin but you can use this plugin for fulfilling your purpose too.

[litextension](http://litextension.com/woocommerce-migration-tool/magento-to-woocommerce.html) plugin might help you. The reason why i gave plugin as a reference to you is of its prompt Live support which resolved all my queries before even purchasing the plugin.

For you to compare they have also given a [comparison link](http://litextension.com/litextension-cart2cart-data-migration-comparison) with cart2cart which you need to crosscheck.